# HTML and Javascript web scraping with VBA

Tags: javascript, html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I am attempting to input values and read values from fields on an internal site I am building using VBA. Up to this point, I have been using the `getElementsByName()` methods to retrieve my data which has been working fine for the plain HTML elements. However, I am now to a portion of my site that includes nested tables and forms and I am getting either a runtime '438' or '91 error using the `getElementsByName()`.

> Run-Time Error #438:
>   Object doesn't support this property or method.
>
> "Runtime Error 91: Object variable or with block variable not set"

I assume this is due to me needing to declare the various parent elements but I don't have any luck. I am attaching the segment of the HTLM that I am trying to retrieve the value from. I am searching for the  tag and need to find the  name out of all the various input tags listed on my forms and tables within the HTML document. Thank you!

```html
</DIV></td>
<td colspan='6' rowspan='2' nowrap='nowrap'  valign='top' align='left'>
<DIV    id='Search'><input type='text' name='RBSearch’ id='RBSearch' tabindex='1977' value=""  class='EDITBOX' style='width:156px; ' maxlength='254' onchange="addchg_win0(this);oChange_win0=this;"  PSnchg='0' /><a class='HYPERLINK'  name='RBSearch_Case' id='RBSearch_Case'  role='button' tabindex='1978' href="javascript:pAction_win0(document.win0,'RBSearch);"><img src="/cs/CRMPRD/cache/PT1.gif" alt='Look up Case' title='Look up (Alt+5)' border='0' align='absmiddle' /></a>
</DIV></td>
```

Comment: Did you try `getElementsByTagName("input")` ?  I'ts not really clear what you're trying to do though - a little more of your current code would help.

Comment: I have attempted to use getElementsByTagName("input").value. The HTML I listed above is part of a secondary HTML form that resides under the main HTML pagelet. I am getting errors when I reference any tag inside the secondary HTML doc but can get the values for any tag in the first HTML doc. My question is, how do I use the getElementsByTagName() function to return values from the tags that are not a part of the first HTML document?

Comment: You don't show enough HTML or enough of your existing code to give a real answer.  You should be aware though that `getElementsByTagName("input")` returns a *collection* of elements, not a single element (if there's only one input then it will still be a single-element collection).  That collection doesn't have a `Value` property: you need to loop over it and look at each member of the collection to find the one you want.

Comment: Thank you Tim, that was my issue.